# Problems with cascading in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to add an address to a person, when I'm saving the address but it doesn't work. I have already tried all variants of cascading. Could anybody help me to solve this problem? In Entities, I left only fields related to my question.

Address Entity

```
public class Address {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "address", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Visitor visitor;
}
```

Visitor Entity

```
public class Visitor {

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    private Address address;

}
```

Address Service

```
public class AddressService {

    private final AddressRepository addressRepository;
    private final VisitorRepository visitorRepository;


    public ResponseEntity<Address> saveAddress(Address address, String visitorId) {
        Visitor visitor = visitorRepository.findById(visitorId).orElseThrow(() -> new VisitorNotFoundException("Visitor with ID: " + visitorId + " not found"));
        Address addressToSave = Address.builder()
                .addressLine(address.getAddressLine())
                .city(address.getCity())
                .zip(address.getZip())
                .visitor(visitor)
                .build();
        addressRepository.save(addressToSave);
        return ResponseEntity.created(
                        ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest()
                                .path("/{id}")
                                .buildAndExpand(addressToSave.getId())
                                .toUri())
                .body(addressToSave);
    }

}
```

VisitorService

```
public class VisitorService {

    private final VisitorRepository visitorRepository;

    public ResponseEntity<Visitor> saveVisitor(Visitor visitor) {
        Visitor visitorToSave = Visitor.builder()
                .address(visitor.getAddress())
                .name(visitor.getName())
                .phoneNumber(visitor.getPhoneNumber())
                .build();
        visitorRepository.save(visitorToSave);
        return ResponseEntity.created(
                        ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest()
                                .path("/{id}")
                                .buildAndExpand(visitorToSave.getId())
                                .toUri())
                .body(visitorToSave);
    }

}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Also as it is a bi-directional relationship make sure you set both and not only the address on the visitor but also the visitor on the address.

Comment: I thought when I save the address it automatically add this address to the person and update in the database

Comment: Not if you don't set both sides of the relationship.

Comment: Could you suggest to me please how to do this properly?

Comment: In the `setAddress` for visitor call `address.setVisitor` and vice/versa. Make sure things only happen if the field is null or not equal to the same instance (else you will get a stackoverflow error).

Answer (score -1):

Have you added @Autowired annotation as like this or not

IN AddressService

```
@Autowired
private final AddressRepository addressRepository;

@Autowired
private final VisitorRepository visitorRepository;
```

In VisitorService

```
 @Autowired
 private final VisitorRepository visitorRepository;
```

Comment: I injected by constructor with @RequiredArgsConstructor lombok annotation

Comment: No you don't as it is injected by constructor which will be happening automatically if there is only one.